# Python function returns None instead of value

Tags: python, area, function

This is my Python code:

```
def pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    base_area = base_length * base_width
    pyramid_volume = base_area * pyramid_height * 1/3
    return

print('Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is:', pyramid_volume(4.5, 2.1, 3.0))
```

It prints `Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is: None`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

In python you have to specify what is to be returned. Like this:

```
def pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width,pyramid_height):
    base_area=base_length*base_width
    pyramid_volume= base_area*pyramid_height*1/3
    return pyramid_volume

print('Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is: ', pyramid_volume(4.5, 2.1, 3.0))
```

Comment: The code by @DavisThuy looks like a practise coming from Pascal (were you specify the return value like this). In python, I'd avoid creating a local variable of the same name as the function (looks unnecessarily confusing to me). Just write `return base_area*pyramid_height*1/3`

Answer (score 0):

Every function in Python returns some object. If no object is specified explicitly, `None` (Python equivalent of `null`) is returned. By writing `return [nothing_here]` you've not specified what's returned, therefore it returns default value (`None`).

As a solution, specify explicitly what shall be returned:

```
def pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    base_area = base_length * base_width
    pyramid_volume = base_area * pyramid_height * 1/3
    return pyramid_volume

print('Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is:', pyramid_volume(4.5, 2.1, 3.0)) # should print value
```